# Crestwood has disappeared from the war table?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

I went to Crestwood once, not sure what happened, but left after opening scene.  I then went on to other areas.  Now Crestwood has disappeared from the war table.

Also, Varric is nowhere to be found.  I did meet him on the ramparts at Skyhold at one point.

Comment: Varric regularly hangs out in the main hall at Skyhold, on the right side next to the door to Solas' study. If he's not there, there's probably some quest active that involves him. Look at your quest journal. There might also be something about Crestwood there.

Answer (score 1):

I had lost him too, I looked everywhere until I found him talking to Hawke in front of the war room. He will be there if you have started the quest Here Lies The Abyss up to where you go to the ritual tower thing and talk to Livius Erimond and then fight the wardens and demons. He then should go back to his usual spot.